# Usage of 方(ほう) in these sentences

Tags: usage, nuances

I know that 方 (ほう) can mean direction or way but that meaning seems to change a bit in the following sentences:

> - 佐藤くん、 英語は得意な方(ほう)かな?
>   Sato, are you good at English?
> - これは割と使ってる方(ほう)です。
>   This is relatively used.

I can kind of intuitively understand why it is used but I want to have a better grasp so that I can use this structure myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the dictionary definition of the usage is the [following](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E6%96%B9-442815):

> どちらかというとその傾向であることをいう語。たぐい。　（＃4　精選版 日本国語大辞典）

So the sentences in the question literally mean:

- Mr Sato, do you tend to be good at English?
- This tends to be used often.

The usage may have derived from the original meaning of *direction* or *side* so that Xするほうだ can be understood as *on the side of X*.

The basic added nuance is *if forced to choose X or not X, then one can say X is true (of the subject)*.  So if making the comparison explicit, the sentences are something like

- 佐藤くん、英語は得意か苦手かといえば得意なほうかな？
- これは使ってるか使ってないかといえば使ってるほうです。

---

Another (though similar) way to look at ほうだ should be a weakening of the statement.

For example, as often said, the Japanese have a strict idea of command in a language, so

- 私は英語が得意です sounds like *I can use English almost as a native speaker*.
- 私は英語が得意なほうです sounds more modest like *I think I can say I'm good at English*.

Another example:

- 酒は強いほうだ *Generally I can drink a lot*
- 私は酒にはつよい would mean capability of drinking like Russians.

---

Note ほうだ can more simply mean a comparative.

- 彼はクラスでは背の高いほうだ He is taller than average in the class.

The above can be considered a version of this usage where the comparison is implicit or vague.

Comment: I heard this meaning used often in conversations, and couldn't find it in J-E dictionaries (e.g., 研究社新和英大辞典). This post is the only English explanation I found :)